# How to force users to nest their comments

Tags: comments, threading

I am trying to figure out how to force commenters to use threaded comments (and not the general comment box at the bottom of the post) on one particular post. I want only admins to be able to post new top-level comments and to force all other users to click the Reply button under the comment to which they are responding.

I've tried using CSS to hide the comment box or to accentuate the Reply link, but it's not working. and it's a terrible hack anyway.

I'm using WordPress 3.8.1, and unfortunately don't have the ability to add plug-ins due to being on @%^&%#^$@# managed hosting. Thanks for any tips or tricks.

Comment: If you have no ability to add plugins or modify code-- assume the two go together-- I doubt there is much that can be done.

Comment: I personally add a message above the comment box only visible to logged in users instructing them about using the reply button. Anyway, correct me if I am wrong but if you have the ability to adjust your CSS through the WP editor, then you should be able to edit plugin codes as well (meaning that you can add a custom filter there)...?

Comment: @ChristineCooper : but I would never advise anyone to edit PHP via the editor. That is a formula for failure, like working on an airplane while it is in the air. :)

Comment: @s_ha_dum I completely agree, but I am looking at all options, which aren't many in this scenario ;)